# What is the feature called that brings you to the file name by typing the first few letters?

Tags: macos, finder

This is not a profound question, but I don't know the answer.

What is the name of the OS behavior that brings you to the file name in a finder window by typing the first few letters?

"Search as you type"?

Comment: Besides file system search engine, I would have to agree with the previous comment: Spotlight is the term given by Apple and Find is simply a general function. Predictive search may be more specific.

Comment: @Tmanok so when I open a finder window, and I type a `d` and then an `a` and the file called `data` becomes highlighted, *this behavior* could be called "spotlight"? I think of spotlight as a utility or application, not a behavior.

Comment: You get me every time uhoh. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204014 Yes it's true that Spotlight works as it's own application and connects to the finder and is capable of bypassing finder windows and opening files and applications without opening or interfacing with a finder window. I apologize for the lack of clarity and my misreading of the question.

Comment: Note this behaviour predates Spotlight by many years. I can't remember when it started, I'd guess way back at System 7 or so.

Comment: Keyboard navigation, but the variant where as long as you dont pause the letters you type stick to the current context

Comment: @JohnKeates I like the way that that one sounds the best, though the term *might be* borrowed from another OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called as 'Code completion' feature or 'Typing intelligence'.

Comment: Aha! Indeed these sounds like behaviors.

Comment: Source for those terms?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a specific name for this behavior, but "type to select" seems like an reasonable, concise way of describing it.

It is *not* autocompletion -- that term specifically refers to behaviors which occur in a text entry context, like an input field or word processing document.